# how to get which action function is used?

Tags: actionfunction

I have these action functions:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="save" action="{!SaveAccount}" oncomplete="executeSD();" status="sub-status"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="executeSD" action="{!saveARecord}" status="sub-status">
<apex:actionFunction name="save_and_new" action="{!SaveAccount}" oncomplete="SN_JS();" status="sub-status"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="SN_JS" action="{!saveDifferentRecord}" status="sub-status"/>
```

The action functions 'save' and 'save_and_new' calls the same apex class function but differs on the oncomplete function call. I realized that the apex functions {!saveARecord} and {!saveDifferentRecord} can be merged in my apex controller class and all i need is to determine which action function is used. How can I detect which action function is being used or how should I write that in my apex controller?

Comment: You can pass a parameter to depending on which method you call. Here is an example of how to use action functions with params. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm

Comment: @Ranga, post this as answer with code examples instead of comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a parameter to depending on which method you call. [Here is an example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) of how to use action functions with params.

```
<!-- Page --> 
<apex:actionFunction name="executeSD" action="{!saveARecord}" status="sub-status">
    <apex:param name="saveStatus" assignTo="{!state}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="SN_JS" action="{!saveARecord}" status="sub-status"/>
    <apex:param name="saveStatus" assignTo="{!state}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<apex:actionFunction name="save" action="{!SaveAccount}" oncomplete="executeSD('save');" status="sub-status"/>
<apex:actionFunction name="save_and_new" action="{!SaveAccount}" oncomplete="SN_JS('saveNew');" status="sub-status"/>

<!-- Controller -->
public static Sting state { get; set; }

public PageReference saveARecord() {
    if(saveStatus == 'save') {
        //redirect to the save
    } else if (saveStatus == 'saveNew') {
        //redirect to save and new
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can pass a parameter from the Action function and in the Apex
>   class

you can check for that parameter and perform the check according to that.

First Create a property in Apex Class. which will look like below

```
public static Sting paramFromJS { get; set; }
```

Define the Action function like below.

```
<apex:actionFunction name="SN_JS" action="{!saveDifferentRecord}" status="sub-status">
     <apex:param name="paramCheck" assignTo="{!paramFromJS}" value="" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Call the action function from the JavaScript and pass the parameter which function is being called.

```
SN_JS('Save')
SN_JS('saveDifferentRecord');
```

Now, in the apex class put the check with this parameter.

```
//..Common Lines
If(paramFromJS == 'Save'){
 //.., Logic Here
}else if(paramFromJS == ''){
 //.. Logic Here
}
```

[apex:actionFunction](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm)